# Summing results from a monte carlo

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

## I am trying to sum the values in the 'Callpayoff' list however am unable to do so, print(Callpayoff) returns a vertical list:

```
0
4.081687878300656
1.6000410648454846
0.5024316862043037
0
```

so I wonder if it's a special sublist ? `sum(Callpayoff)` does not work unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def Generate_asset_price(S,v,r,dt):
    return (1 + r * dt + v * sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(0,1))

def Call_Poff(S,T):
    return max(stream[-1] - S,0)


# initial values
S = 100
v = 0.2
r = 0.05
T = 1
N = 2 # number of steps 
dt = 0.00396825
simulations = 5

for x in range(simulations):
    stream = [100]
    Callpayoffs = []
    t = 0
    for n in range(N):
        s = stream[t] * Generate_asset_price(S,v,r,dt)
        stream.append(s)
        t += 1
        Callpayoff = Call_Poff(S,T)
    print(Callpayoff)
    plt.plot(stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're not appending values to a list, you're just replacing the value of `Callpayoff` at each iteration and printing it. At each iteration, it's printed on a new line so it looks like a "vertical list".

What you need to do is use `Callpayoffs.append(Call_Poff(S,T))` instead of `Callpayoff = Call_Poff(S,T)`.

Now a new element will be added to `Callpayoffs` at every iteration of the `for` loop.

Then you can print the list with `print(Callpayoffs)` or the sum with `print(sum(Callpayoffs))`

All in all the `for` loop should look like this:

```
for x in range(simulations):
    stream = [100]
    Callpayoffs = []
    t = 0
    for n in range(N):
        s = stream[t] * Generate_asset_price(S,v,r,dt)
        stream.append(s)
        t += 1
        Callpayoffs.append(Call_Poff(S,T))
    print(Callpayoffs,"sum:",sum(Callpayoffs))
```

Output:

```
[2.125034975231003, 0] sum: 2.125034975231003
[0, 0] sum: 0
[0, 0] sum: 0
[0, 0] sum: 0
[3.2142923036024342, 4.1390018820809615] sum: 7.353294185683396
```